# How to Remove Specific CSS Files

Tags: magento2

How do I delete the following files from the front end?

Here is the code I inserted.
It doesn't work.

> **magento/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <remove src="Magento_Theme::mage/calendar.css"/>
    <remove src="Amasty_ShopbyBase::css/swiper.min.css"/>
</head>
```

Then, after editing and saving, I executed the following command:

```
sudo php71 bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php71 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php71 bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php71 bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Have you run `php bin/magento s:s:d -f` command?

Comment: I just changed my question.

Comment: Code seems ok, What is the location of this layout?

Comment: magento/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: This is the location of the layout.

Answer (score 6):

You are going in the right way, you can remove css from xml file.

Let see `calendar.css` it is added from vendor `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default_head_blocks.xml` and the file code to add this file is:

```
<head>
    <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
</head>
```

Now to remove this file just use path, not `Magento_Theme`

Like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in **default_head_blocks.xml** :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="name.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

[Remove static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove)